# xcode crashes when opening project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a problem with xcode. I have worked on iphone project and opened it normally. But today I can not open it. when I try to open it xcode crashes with log:

```
    ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFoundation/IDEFoundation-937/Framework/Classes/Model/Logging/ActivityLog/IDEActivityLogSection.m:771
Details:  Assertion failed: nBytesRead <= sizeof(buffer)
Object:   <IDEActivityLogSection>
Method:   +sectionWithContentsOfFile:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x200025720>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001009e6646 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010006aaa4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010061a094 +[IDEActivityLogSection sectionWithContentsOfFile:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  3  0x000000010057b84d -[IDEOnDiskActivityLogRecord fullLogWithError:] (in IDEFoundation)
  4  0x00000001006bad4b __79-[IDEOnDiskActivityLogRecord initWithUUID:store:cacheEntry:updatedCache:error:]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEFoundation)
  5  0x00000001006bac48 -[IDEOnDiskActivityLogRecord initWithUUID:store:cacheEntry:updatedCache:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  6  0x000000010057b46c __60-[IDEOnDiskLogStore_Impl initWithRootDirectoryAtPath:error:]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x00007fff87e5a4da __NSDictionaryEnumerate (in CoreFoundation)
  8  0x000000010057b256 -[IDEOnDiskLogStore_Impl initWithRootDirectoryAtPath:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  9  0x0000000100579cf9 +[IDEOnDiskLogStore onDiskStoreInWorkspaceArena:atSubPath:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
 10  0x0000000100579bcb +[IDELogStore onDiskOrInMemoryLogStoreInWorkspaceArena:prefix:] (in IDEFoundation)
 11  0x0000000100579aaa -[IDEExecutionEnvironment initWithWorkspaceArena:] (in IDEFoundation)
 12  0x0000000100579863 -[IDEWorkspace _setupExecutionEnvironment] (in IDEFoundation)
 13  0x00000001005e10f4 -[IDEWorkspace _setupWorkspaceArenaIfNeeded] (in IDEFoundation)
 14  0x00000001005e13fe __81-[IDEWorkspace _finishLoadingAsynchronously:shouldUpgradeFromSimpleFilesFocused:]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEFoundation)
 15  0x00007fff83e8290d -[NSBlockOperation main] (in Foundation)
 16  0x00007fff83e72dd0 -[__NSOperationInternal start] (in Foundation)
 17  0x00007fff83f50bd5 ____NSOQSchedule_block_invoke_2 (in Foundation)
 18  0x00007fff88698d64 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 19  0x00007fff886778d2 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 20  0x00007fff8867817f _dispatch_queue_serial_drain_till_empty (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 21  0x00007fff886aaf1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 22  0x00007fff87df4c60 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 23  0x00007fff87df3d8f CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 24  0x00007fff89b937ee RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 25  0x00007fff89b935f3 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 26  0x00007fff89b934ac BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
 27  0x00007fff83481eb2 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 28  0x00007fff83481801 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 29  0x00007fff8344768f -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 30  0x00007fff834403b0 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 31  0x0000000100000eec
```

help me please to solve this problem.
xcode 4.2

Comment: This is a bug to report to Apple, not a programming question.

Comment: I removed all of the repositories from xcode's organizer. the repository section is empty now. But this didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you rename the Xcode project, from the Project Folder by any chance?             Are you getting this error when compiling the project, or when you are loading it?(i suppose the second, from your message)

Comment: I renamed the directory with the project and now it works fine